# How to resize a video's aspect ratio without affecting its proportions (unround numbers)

Tags: video, resize, resolution, aspect-ratio, video-editing

I'm trying to resize a video with a resolution of 2000x1080 and an aspect ratio of 1.852 (50:27) to HD resolution (not FHD). The problem with this is that I can't get a round number for both width and height around the 1280p width mark or 720p height mark. Best round number I got was at 1300x702.

Now to my real question: Is it natural to assume that the video will lose its aspect ratio if I convert 1280x691.2 to 1280x691 (ignoring its fractional part)? If so, is the only workaround to maintain the aspect ratio is to look for the nearest round resolution?

Comment: What have you decided to do?

Comment: @g-hos I decided not to resize it since the aspect ratio is odd.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

converting from 691.2 to 691 is meaningless in video. It is always pixels (even and multiple of 16 if you go for compression). It's already odd resolution, either keep the aspect ratio or resize to 720p thereby losing aspect ration. One more thing is to reduce to 1350x729 and crop 70 columns and 9 rows, here you will lose the content (or information). Choose one of these as per your application.

Comment: Thanks for the response!